# Executing multiple statements in procedure simultaneously

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I want to execute multiple DDL statements present in my procedure to start at once.Say

create or replace procedure test  is

```
a number;
b number;
c number;
d number;
e number;
f number;
g number;
h number;
i number;
j number;

begin

create table t1 as select * from test1 where id between  a and b;

create table t2 as select * from test2 where id between  c and d;

create table t3 as select * from test3 where id between  e and f;

create table t4 as select * from test4  where id between  g and h;

create table t5 as select * from test5 where id between  i and j;


end test;
```

let's assume this is my proc and I want all the 5 statements to be executed at once and not one after another. How this can be achieved

Comment: PL/SQL is not designed that way, it works sequentially. To perform actions asynchronously/in parallel use [`DBMS_SCHEDULER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html)

Comment: Oh, I've already suggested you the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73970322/processing-records-in-batches#comment130607701_73970322. What is wrong with that approach?

Comment: Instead of creating 5 separate tables, how about creating a single range partitioned table? That way, you can specify the ranges within the table, and insert data into all partitions in a single transaction. You can query the table by partition if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Statements executed through 1 connection are executed one after the other in the session of the connection. Execution in parallel will require several connections and some way to tell which statement is the next to execute (for example a queue mechanism, in your case it can be a table where you put kind of ID to specify which is the next step (in an autonomous transaction, for other sessions to see the commited data)).

Answer (score 0):

With the package :  dbms_scheduler.create_job you can run your statements in parallel.
for more information:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/scheduling-jobs-with-oracle-scheduler.html#GUID-D41660D0-D88F-4D9F-8CC8-63D040EDC4E6